# apt-get update not working

Tags: apt, updates, lubuntu, plex

guys please help me unable to apt-get update

the output is

```
20% [9 InRelease gpgv 23.4 kB] [7 Sources 76.5 kB/1,064 kB 7%] [Waiting for heaSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/www.plexapp.com_repo_dists_lucid_InReleasIgn hp://ww.plexapp.com lucid InRelease                                     
E: GPG error: http://www.plexapp.com lucid InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
draguve@Patil-Server:~$
```

Full Output :
https://justpaste.it/hajh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Plex repository entry is outdated. Download the new package from [the Plex site](https://plex.tv/downloads/) and install it.

If you can't do that for some reason, update it manually. I checked the [Ubuntu package for Plex](https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server/0.9.9.14.531-7eef8c6/plexmediaserver_0.9.9.14.531-7eef8c6_amd64.deb) (current version: `0.9.9.14.531-7eef8c6`). They may have used `http://plexapps.com` as their repository in the past, but at some point they swicthed to a different mirror. The contents of the `sources.list.d` list file in the package is:

```
deb http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer/ubuntu-repo lucid main
```

Presumably both repositories were active for some time, but now the first one isn't. You should disable the first and enable the new one:

```
sudo mv $(grep -l 'www.plexapp.com' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list){,.bak}
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list <<EOF
deb http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer/ubuntu-repo lucid main
EOF
```

This should fix your problem with Plex.

NOTE: It seems they use `lucid` for all Ubuntu packages. So do not take that as an indication that the packages are meant only for Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem since a week ago and nope, it doesn't fix the problem.  It seems that http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer doesn't exist anymore.  There is a server at http://plex.r.worldssl.net though.

No idea what's going on there, but maybe something to take up with the Plex dev team.